# 24" - 27" monitor recommendation

Tags: monitors

I'd like to purchase some 24" or 27" monitor.
The must features: built-in speakers and adjustable height.
I'm not a gamer, I'm a programmer, sitting in front of the monitor 10+ hours daily.
I guess it should be IPS monitor, but VA can be considered as well.
Someone told me 144Hz refreshing rate will reduce eye fatigue.
Not looking for expensive models.
What would you advice?

Comment: I am programmer too, and have no problems with my 60Hz monitor, I don't think high refresh rate will reduce eye vatigue, I think its mostly panel type

Comment: You don't need a massive refresh-rate to view essentially static images. I have a 'live' fps indicator on my desktop. With 'nothing happening' it drops down to single figures. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf6lH.jpg That number will suddenly jump higher if I generate motion such as scrolling or dragging a window around. I'd suggest your search should consider whether at 27" you want a 4k or 2k screen. I'm perfectly happy with a couple of 27" 2ks for 12 hours a day, but some people like a sharper image than that these days.

Comment: Thank you @Irsu85 and Tetsujin. Can you mention / advice some specific models?

Comment: I'm still using a couple of 2k Dell 27" displays, nearly a decade old. They're great & colour accurate to Adobe RGB using a colorimeter workflow, which I absolutely need for photography/film. U2713H - the 2713 is obviously size & year, but the U & H are the 'quality'. I wouldn't hesitate to recommend those or their current equivalents. I originally got them because they were reputedly using the same 'glass' as the Apple Cinema Displays of the time, but had non-reflective coatings whereas the Apples were too shiny for my needs.

Comment: They don't have speakers, but I'm a sound engineer by trade so have rather specialist speakers in my workroom, costing far more than both the displays.

Comment: I got a full hd Samsung TV (27 inch), which is also pretty old. I really like it being pretty bright and sharp vs my other monitors. Its also big enough to fit bulky IDE's like CLion.

Comment: I honestly would never use a 1k 27" screen for anything other than watching TV. 2k minimum spec for 27".

Answer (score 1):

I currently bought BenQ GW2485TC and I really recommend it for coding. First, it's 24 inch, height adjustable and has built-in speakers that meets your needs, and it has multiple eye care features (BenQ is well-known for the eye care technology) which  really help reduce eye strain for hours of working. Plus, it supports a special color mode called "coding mode", and it's really worthy to try!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I actually already bought AOC 27G2U5/BK. 27", all the features I was looking for.

Comment: you are welcome, enjoy your new monitor :)